# Where is LLVMSystem.a

Tags: makefile, llvm

I'm new to `LLVM` and now I'm following the document
http://llvm.org/releases/2.9/docs/UsingLibraries.html#always

(since I'm using `LLVM 2.9`)to add libraries into the `makefile`. It says a rule of thumb is to add `LLVMSystem` lib into the `makefile` but I can find it nowhere in the source code nor built directory. Can someone let me know where it is and is it really needed to add this library at all times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me once again point to the [LLVM & Clang samples repository](https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples). It comes with a [Makefile](https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples/blob/master/Makefile) which builds with modern versions of LLVM, as well as older released versions (in branches of the repository). The Makefile shows which LLVM libs to link to your program for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Im not using `LLVM 2.9` but `3.2` and I am linking vs. following libraries (Im using a Windows environment but I wouldnt think that matters). I've got those from the Kaleidoscope tutorial at http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/index.html

```
LLVMAnalysis.lib
LLVMArchive.lib
LLVMAsmParser.lib
LLVMAsmPrinter.lib
LLVMBitReader.lib
LLVMBitWriter.lib
LLVMCodeGen.lib
LLVMCore.lib
LLVMDebugInfo.lib
LLVMExecutionEngine.lib
LLVMInstCombine.lib
LLVMInstrumentation.lib
LLVMInterpreter.lib
LLVMipa.lib
LLVMipo.lib
LLVMJIT.lib
LLVMLinker.lib
LLVMMC.lib
LLVMMCDisassembler.lib
LLVMMCJIT.lib
LLVMMCParser.lib
LLVMObject.lib
LLVMRuntimeDyld.lib
LLVMScalarOpts.lib
LLVMSelectionDAG.lib
LLVMSupport.lib
LLVMTableGen.lib
LLVMTarget.lib
LLVMTransformUtils.lib
LLVMVectorize.lib
LLVMX86AsmParser.lib
LLVMX86AsmPrinter.lib
LLVMX86CodeGen.lib
LLVMX86Desc.lib
LLVMX86Disassembler.lib
LLVMX86Info.lib
LLVMX86Utils.lib
```